# Create several line breaks in excel cell using Excel VBA

Tags: excel

I will try to explain the issue as clear as possible.
I have a column in an Excel file and each cell in this column contains a description of some issue. The description has four levels such as `Name`, `Issue`, `Solution` and `Result`, all these four in the same cell.

I need VBA code that will find each level in each cell and create line break in the cell.
So instead of this:

```
Name: 123 Issue: My issue: Solution: Try to resolve Result: Resolved.
```

After the code runs will be like this:

```
  Name: 123 (line break) 
  Issue: My issue (line break) 
  Solution: Try to resolve (line break)  
  Result: Resolved (line break)
```

Please let me know if there is any solution?

Comment: Sorry @user2190035 - think my edit overwrote yours.  So a line break is defined as the first space before the `:` symbol?  How are the descriptions added to the cells in the first place?  Could the line breaks be added at that time?  What have you tried so far?  Have you tried using the `vbcr` command to  add the line break where needed?

Answer (score 1):

loop through the cells and add linefeeds.

```
sub makelfs()

    dim i as long, j as long, arr as variant, str as string

    arr = array("Issue:","Solution:","Result:")

    with worksheets("excel file")

        for i=2 to .cells(.rows.count, "a column in excel file").end(xlup).row
            str = .cells(i, "a column in excel file").value2
            for j = lbound(arr) to ubound(arr)
                str = replace(str, arr(j), vblf & arr(j)) 
            next j
            .cells(i, "a column in excel file") = str
            .cells(i, "a column in excel file").wraptext = true
        next i

    end with

end sub
```

Comment: I would remove the array. You don't need it for this special case of three replacements. Just use three times `Replace`.

Comment: This isn't just for the op but maybe he/she can learn something.

Comment: Thank you. The solution works for me and the array is actually good as I have more than three replacements. One more ask though, can I format all the ("Issue:","Solution:","Result:") to bold? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Select the cell containing the data and run:

```
Sub FixData()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveCell
    t = r.Text
    t = Replace(t, "Issue:", Chr(10) & "Issue:")
    t = Replace(t, "Solution:", Chr(10) & "Solution:")
    t = Replace(t, "Result:", Chr(10) & "Result:")
    r.Value = t
    r.WrapText = True
End Sub
```

If necessary, you can put this in a loop.

Comment: Good point about the .WrapText, I had neglected that in my own.

Comment: @DenisLomakin  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "Name: 123 Issue: My issue: Solution: Try to resolve Result: Resolved."
arr = Split(s, Chr(32))
For Each Item In arr
    If cnt > 0 Then
        If Right(Item, 1) = ":" Then Item = vbCrLf & Item
    End If

    output = output & Item & " "
    cnt = cnt + 1
Next Item
Debug.Print output
```

Comment: I notice an errant colon in the input string, but this (currently) matches the question

Comment: Yep, spotted that as well.  Good answer if the colon is removed though.

Answer (score 0):

Using a slightly different approach which doesn't rely on `Issue`, `Solution` and `Result` being present.
As said in my comment - look for the first space before the colon and replace it with a line feed (put `vbcr` in my comment - should be `vblf`).

```
Public Function AddLineBreak(Target As Range) As String

    Dim lColon As Long
    Dim lSpace As Long

    Dim sFinal As String

    sFinal = Target.Value
    lSpace = Len(sFinal)

    Do While lSpace <> 0

        sFinal = Left(sFinal, lSpace - 1) & Replace(sFinal, " ", vbLf, lSpace, 1)

        lColon = InStrRev(sFinal, ":", lSpace - 1)
        lSpace = InStrRev(sFinal, " ", lColon)

    Loop

    AddLineBreak = Trim(sFinal)

End Function
```

You can call the function in a procedure:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In Sheet1.Range("A1:A13")
        rCell = AddLineBreak(rCell)
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

or as a worksheet function:
`=AddLineBreak(A1)`

This assumes an error in the original string you posted:
`Name: 123 Issue: My issue: Solution: Try to resolve Result: Resolved.`  should be
`Name: 123 Issue: My issue Solution: Try to resolve Result: Resolved.`
(extra colon before `Solution` which is not shown in your *After code* example).

Edit - it also means you cannot have spaces in your headings.  So you can have " Issue:" or " My_Issue:" but not " My Issue:"